# Using the lcc-win compiler from the command line

Tags: c, windows, compiler-construction, command-line, lcc-win32

I have installed the [lcc compiler](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~lcc-win32/) so that I can compile c programs on my windows machine - but I am having troubles getting it to work...

I added C:\lcc\bin to my PATH environment variable, but when I type in:

```
lcc args
```

into my command line, I get this message: 'lcc is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file'.

If I actually navigate to the folder C:\lcc\bin, I can execute lcc no problem

Is there something else I have to do other than set the PATH variable?

thanks!

Comment: How did you add it to your PATH? When you're in the same command window that shows the error message,  if you type `set PATH` and hit Enter, do you see `c:\lcc\bin` in the output?

Comment: I just went Computer>Advanced Settings> Environment variables, then tacked on ;C:\lcc\bin

Comment: changing the path using the advanced settings dialog like that will only affect the path of cmd.exe sessions that are started *after* you make the change. If your cmd.exe was already open, you'll need to manually change that one via path=c:\lcc\bin;%path%

Comment: That's half of what I asked. :) Did you do that with the command window already open? Do you see it in the `PATH` if you use the instructions I mentioned before?

Comment: fwiw, you may have to do set include=c:\lcc\include and probably lib, too.

Comment: Once I typed in set PATH in the cmd, I noticed that there was a space in the path :( like C:\ lcc\bin. thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

I had also problems using lcc. By accident I started the editor that was also included in the package. Since then it works. I notice that I have to perform this operation each time I install it on a new computer. I suppose that it has to do with some initialization files that are required, but only created by the editor. Maybe this will also helps you.